# Event handler in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, event-handling, datatemplate

I have WPF ComboBox inside a data template (a lot of comboboxes in listbox) and I want to handle enter button. It would be easy if it was e.g. a button - I would use Command + Relative binding path etc. Unfortunately, I have no idea how handle key press with a Command or how to set event handler from template.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved my problem by using a usual event handler where I walk through the visual tree, find corresponding button and call it's command.
If anybody else has the same problem, please post a comment and I'll provide more details of realization.

**UPD**

Here is my solution:

I search the visual tree for a button and than execute command associated with button.

View.xaml:

```
<ComboBox KeyDown="ComboBox_KeyDown"/>
<Button Command="{Binding AddResourceCommand}"/>
```

View.xaml.cs:

```
private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)sender);
        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as Button;
            if (null != child)
            {
                child.Command.Execute(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use the EventSetter in the style you are setting the template with:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseWheel" Handler="GroupListBox_MouseWheel" />
      <Setter Property="Template" ... />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This article has a way to route any `Event` to `Command`

http://nerobrain.blogspot.nl/2012/01/wpf-events-to-command.html

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option is to derive the control like this

```
  public class MyTextbox : TextBox
  {
    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Handled = true;
      //...
      return;
    }

    private void OnGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      //E.g. delete the content when focused
      e.Handled = true;
      this.Text = null;
      return;
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
      base.OnApplyTemplate();
      this.GotKeyboardFocus += OnGotKeyboardFocus;
      this.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
    }
  }
```

If you just want the control to behave always like this, instead of adding the events in  OnApplyTemplate() you can of course directly override the virtual methods e.g.

```
    protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Handled = true;
      this.Text = null;
      return;
    }
```