# Hide the ToggleButton on WPF Expander via Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expander

I am trying to dynamically hide the Toggle Button on an Expander using a Property on my ViewModel set to the Visibility property. At least that is my thought. Is there a way to just alter that one setting on the ToggleButton control without having to do the ENTIRE template of the Toggle Button in my xaml?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `Loaded` event for the `Expander` and set up the `Binding` in the event handler or if you want a reusable way without code behind you could use an attached behavior.

The attached behavior finds the `ToggleButton` inside the `Template` and sets up the `Binding` to the attached property `ToggleButtonVisibility`.

Uploaded a sample app here: [ExpanderToggleButtonVisibilityTest.zip](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/ExpanderToggleButtonVisibilityTest.zip)

Use it like this

```
<Expander Name="expander"
          behaviors:ExpanderBehavior.BindToggleButtonVisibility="True"
          behaviors:ExpanderBehavior.ToggleButtonVisibility="{Binding YourVisibilityProperty}"
          .../>
```

*ExpanderBehavior*

```
public class ExpanderBehavior
{
    public static DependencyProperty BindToggleButtonVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindToggleButtonVisibility",
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(ExpanderBehavior),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnBindToggleButtonVisibilityChanged));

    public static bool GetBindToggleButtonVisibility(Expander expander)
    {
        return (bool)expander.GetValue(BindToggleButtonVisibilityProperty);
    }
    public static void SetBindToggleButtonVisibility(Expander expander, bool value)
    {
        expander.SetValue(BindToggleButtonVisibilityProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnBindToggleButtonVisibilityChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Expander expander = target as Expander;
        if (expander.IsLoaded == true)
        {
            BindToggleButtonVisibility(expander);
        }
        else
        {
            RoutedEventHandler loadedEventHandler = null;
            loadedEventHandler = new RoutedEventHandler(delegate
            {
                BindToggleButtonVisibility(expander);
                expander.Loaded -= loadedEventHandler;
            });
            expander.Loaded += loadedEventHandler;
        }
    }

    private static void BindToggleButtonVisibility(Expander expander)
    {
        ToggleButton headerSite = expander.Template.FindName("HeaderSite", expander) as ToggleButton;
        if (headerSite != null)
        {
            Binding visibilityBinding = new Binding
            {
                Source = expander,
                Path = new PropertyPath(ToggleButtonVisibilityProperty)
            };
            headerSite.SetBinding(ToggleButton.VisibilityProperty, visibilityBinding);
        }
    }

    #region ToggleButtonVisibilityProperty

    public static DependencyProperty ToggleButtonVisibilityProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ToggleButtonVisibility",
                                            typeof(Visibility),
                                            typeof(ExpanderBehavior),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

    public static Visibility GetToggleButtonVisibility(Expander expander)
    {
        return (Visibility)expander.GetValue(ToggleButtonVisibilityProperty);
    }
    public static void SetToggleButtonVisibility(Expander expander, Visibility value)
    {
        expander.SetValue(ToggleButtonVisibilityProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion // ToggleButtonVisibilityProperty
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at doing this.

Comment: Besides re-templating, you also have another option. You could subclass ´Expander` and find the `ToggleButton` in `OnApplyTemplate`. I dont have access to my computer now so I cant give an example but you can find something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111756/in-wpf-how-to-add-an-eventhandler-for-a-frameworkelement-designed-in-template