# How to hide toggle button from Expander in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows

I want to hide the toggle button in Expander as I am new to WPF.

Expander is inside a datagrid template.

here is the code

```
<DataTemplate >
  <StackPanel >

    <Expander  Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="Auto" Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed" PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="Expander_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" >

      <Expander.Header>
        <Border x:Name="brdr_header" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black"   CornerRadius="0">

          <Grid x:Name="InnerData" Width="Auto" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition  />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the "Designer" view in visual studio you can

> right click on the expander -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy

Then choose were to put the style. And remove the toggle button and its triggers in the template. Done!

You can also restyle it if you want to,.

Answer (score 1):

You could retemplate the control, or follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111756/in-wpf-how-to-add-an-eventhandler-for-a-frameworkelement-designed-in-template) example where you get the Templated Child of the control, and can manipulate it from there :)

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original style using Expression Blend (if you don't have a key use the trial version). If you got the style you can do anything you want to change the view; e.g. removing the toggle button.